# Bank Payments via PayPal REST API

Tags: api, rest, paypal, payment, bank

I am attempting to use the PayPal REST API to process a bank transaction using the a bank account and routing number.

Here is the ref for the api that I am using for testing: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Here is my JSON:

```
{
   "intent":"sale",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"bank",
      "funding_instruments":[
         {
            "bank_account":{
               "account_number":"01234567890123456",
               "account_number_type":"BBAN",
               "routing_number":"012345678",
               "account_type":"Checking",
               "account_name":"Test Account",
               "auth_type":"WEB",
               "first_name":"John",
               "last_name":"Doe",
               "birth_date":"1970-01-01",
               "billing_address":{
                  "line1":"Somewhere Street",
                  "line2":"Suite 200",
                  "city":"Atlanta",
                  "country_code":"US",
                  "postal_code":"30350",
                  "state":"GA"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "transactions":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"100"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the response from the call:
"{\"name\":\"NOT_IMPLEMENTED\",\"message\":\"NOT_IMPLEMENTED\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#NOT_IMPLEMENTED\",\"debug_id\":\"53fd10d0a05c\"}"

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that "bank_account" is a valid option for funding_instruments. The docs only lists "credit_card" and "credit_card_token"

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#fundinginstrument-object